# How to lock android sim network?

Tags: mobile-network, android-sdk

I want to manually lock the android sim card network is that possible and how to do it?

Comment: Did you mean disable SIM Card Network? If so, your device should have SIM Management Option in Settings App. From there You should be able to disable specific SIM and that way you are kind of Locking That SIM's Network coverage!!

Answer (score 1):

From your homescreen ….

- Tap the <kbd>menu</kbd> button/key
- Select "Settings"
- In the network settings, tap "more…"
- Then tap "Mobile networks"
- On the next screen, select "Network Operators"
- Instead of "Select automatically", select your network operator manually here

[image: network selection]
<sup>Network selection screen (click for larger variant)</sup>

Note that the network must be available in order for you to select it. You cannot e.g. select an US network operator while you're in China :)